# How do I change the list of pair to list of string

Tags: haskell

how do I change the list of pair[("aabb", 12), ("eegg", 9)]

into

["aabb 12", "eegg 9"] list of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for comprehension seems to be the most readable solution here:

```
 [x ++ " " ++ show y | (x,y) <- [("aabb", 12), ("eegg", 9)]]
```

Answer (score 7):

As easy as that:

```
map (\(str, i) -> str ++ ' ':show i) [("aabb", 12), ("eegg", 9)]
```

Comment: Why do you add so many parens? As chunksof50 says, `str ++ ' ' : show i` works and is just fine. The less obvious parsing is irrelevant here, since concatenations are associative (and any way you'd misparse the expression would result in a type error). In particular, you never need parens around something like `show i` as an infix argument, since function application has higher precedence than any infix.

Answer (score 3):

An more pointfree alternative style would be:

```
map (uncurry (++) . fmap (' ':) . fmap show) $ [("aabb", 12), ("eegg", 9)]
```

I'm reporting this as a curiosity. I find markusw answer simpler and more readable.

*EDIT*: Update from Nikita's comment.

Comment: 1. No need for arrow, since a pair is a `Functor` over the second item. 2. Zipping-unzipping looks like overkill. I suggest `map (uncurry (++) . fmap (' ':) . fmap show) list`

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, I didn't notice until now that `(,)` is a `Functor` instance. Thanks, til.